# I am using laravel framework. It says The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

Post method in form working on local but when i clone the same code to the VM it is not working.

```
Route::get('AnswerType/Save','Admin\AnswerTypeController@store'); //route

{!! Form::open(['url' => '/master-data/AnswerType/', 'method'=>'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!} //form

public function store(Request $request) //controller
{
    // validate
    request()->validate([
        'form.AnswerTypeName' => ['required', 'max:250'],
    ]);

    // save
    $security_group = AnswerType::create($request->form);

    // msg
    session()->flash('message-success', 'The Answer type was successfully created.');

    // redirect
    return redirect('/master-data/AnswerType/View');
}
```

Comment: could you share some code snippets indicating your routes?

Comment: Please show the controller function, your route defenition and the view. Also post any error if available.

Comment: it is working on local. but in VM it is not working

Comment: [Could it be a caching problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878951/how-to-clear-route-caching-on-server-laravel-5-2-37?answertab=votes#tab-top)