# is there any method to find out current path of route file in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have started working in a existing laravel project, I found all the routes placed in routes/web.php as usual. But When I declare a new route it does not work even not found on artisan `route:list` command.

So what I've tried so far is finding out how existing routes are working, for that I just deleted some routes from existing routes/web.php file, But I was just wondered finding it has no effect over the project. all the deleted routes still redirects to specified methods of the controllers and all the functionalities are working fine. so it looks like there is another file to place the routes instead of default web.php

I have cleared all the caches like

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

all the routes on web.php are as below

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

//all routes are declared here like
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); //example route
});
```

So is there any way to find out the route file working behind the scene?

Or is it really possible to change the default path of route file then routes/web.php?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878951/how-to-clear-route-caching-on-server-laravel-5-2-37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've cleared a number of caches, but not your route cache.

Try running `php artisan route:clear` to clear your route cache.

Your routes are cached after you run `php artisan route:cache`, this is sometimes included in your `composer.json` scripts so can occur without you even being aware.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file which serves for all routes settings `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`. It has method map() where it binds both routes files – web and API:

```
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

    }

    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```