# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I am getting this error on form submission:
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
Here is the form code:

```
<form action="bid" method = "POST" >
    @csrf
    <h2>
        Your Bid
    </h2>
    <h4 style="font-size:15px;color:antiquewhite">Days</h4>
                                    <input type="number" name="days" placeholder=" Your Days to complete project" class="form-input"><br />
                                    <h4 style="font-size:15px;color:antiquewhite">Cost</h4>
                                    <input type="number" name="cost" placeholder="Your bid cost in $ doller" class="form-input"><br />
                                    <button class="btnn-U" type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

and here is the Route code:

```
Route::post('bid','App\Http\Controllers\register@bid');
```

I have tried using `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878951/how-to-clear-laravel-route-caching-on-server php

Comment: I saw this answer before but this didn't help

Comment: You deleted the cache file?

Comment: Which version laravel are you using?

Comment: @Dmitry I am using laravel 9

Comment: @Foobar I read that it solved this problem sometimes so I did it

Comment: can you try "php artisan route:list | grep bid" and add a screenshot to the question?

Comment: I would start with using named routes and don't hardcode form actions. `action="{{ route('bid') }}"` (and add a name to the route)

Comment: Post complete codes from the route.php file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, a recommendation, write your routes like this and give your route any name;

```
Route::post('bid','App\Http\Controllers\register@bid');

to

Route::post('bid',[\App\Http\Controllers\register::class, 'bid'])->name('uniqueRouteName');
```

And call this route with name;

```
<form action="{{ route('uniqueRouteName') }}" method = "POST" >
        @csrf
        <h2>
            Your Bid
        </h2>
        <h4 style="font-size:15px;color:antiquewhite">Days</h4>
        <input type="number" name="days" placeholder=" Your Days to complete project" class="form-input"><br />
        <h4 style="font-size:15px;color:antiquewhite">Cost</h4>
        <input type="number" name="cost" placeholder="Your bid cost in $ doller" class="form-input"><br />
        <button class="btnn-U" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @talha This made the problem even worse. 
``` Route [projectBid] not defined.```

Comment: @RehmanAli did you add the route name to the route and did you run `php artisan route:clear` ? This is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="/bid" method = "POST" >`
Tried different things but ultimately this solved my problem.

Comment: Might work, but is not a good solution. Hardcoded routes are a bad idea